# bounding the number of zeros for a multivariate polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $f \in \mathbb{F}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be a nonzero polynomial such that the maximum exponent of each variable is $d.$ I would like to show that for any $S \subseteq \mathbb{F}$ of size $|S| \geq d$ there are at least $(|S|-d)^n$ points in $S^n$ for which $f$ is not zero.

I would like to prove the above claim by induction on $n.$ For the inductive step I am suggested to fix a $(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \in \mathbb{F}^n$ and consider the multinomials $$g(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1}) = f(x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1},a_n) \quad \mbox{and} \quad h(x_n) = f(a_1, \ldots,a_{n-1},x_n).$$

By the induction hypothesis we would then have at least $(S-d)^{n-1}$ points that are not a zero for $g$ and $S-d$ points that are not zero for $h.$ But I do not see how to proceed from here?

Can someone suggest a proof of this fact?

Comment: Hint: in a field $\mathbb{F}$, given polynomials $a,b,c\in \mathbb{F}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ with $a=bc$ we know $a = 0 \iff b=0$ or $c=0$.

Comment: @AlexJBest Can you be more direct with this hint please? Somehow I don't get it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simpler notation, let $k=|S|-d, N=\{(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)\in S^n: f(\alpha_1,...\alpha_n)\neq 0\}.$
The induction base is the well known fact that a polynomial $f\in K[x]$ has at most $\text{deg}f$ roots in $K$. Let $\Bbb E=\Bbb F(x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1}).$ We view $f$ as a polynomial in one variable with coefficients in $\Bbb E,$ i.e. let $h(x_n)=f(x_1,...,x_n)\in \Bbb E[x_n].$ By the induction base there are at least $k$ elements $a_1, a_2,...,a_k$ in $S$ such that $h(a_i)\neq 0$. For $1\le i\le k$ define $g_i(x_1,...,x_{n-1})=f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},a_i)\in \Bbb F[x_1,...,x_n]$ and $S_i=\{(b_1,...,b_{n-1})\in S^{n-1}:g(b_1,...,b_{n-1})\neq 0\}.$ By the induction hypothesis $|S_i|\ge k^{n-1}$ for each $i$, hence $|N|\ge k\cdot k^{n-1}=k^n$.

Comment: Hm.. I kind of don't understand this proof. Is there a way to rephrase it without treating the polynomials as being from $\mathbb{E}[x_n]$? Thanks..

Comment: The idea behind my proof is to somehow show that there are at least $k$ elements $a_1,...,a_k$ of $S$ such that $f(x_1,...,x_{n-1},a_i)\in \Bbb F[x_1,...,x_{n-1}]$ is a non-zero polynomial (otherwise we cannot apply the induction hypothesis).

Comment: Then every such polynomial has at least $k^{n-1}$ non-zeros $(b_1,...,b_{n-1})\in S^{n-1}$ and each of these gives us a non-zero $(b_1,...,b_{n-1},a_i)$ of $f$. Therefore there at least $k\cdot k^{n-1}$ non-zeros of $f$.